# Inherit another UI library selector properties in a component attribute selector

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-components, ng-zorro-antd

I have a buildable/publishable Angular library which I want to wrap [`ng-zorro`](https://ng.ant.design/docs/introduce/en) button (and other components as well one-by-one) within to add my attribute selector instead of the `ng-zorro` selector and add more properties to the original component.

In the [source code](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/components/button/button.component.ts) of `ng-zorro`, you can see that the `nz-button` attribute is implemented like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'button[nz-button], a[nz-button]',
  exportAs: 'nzButton',
  preserveWhitespaces: false,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  template: `
    <span nz-icon nzType="loading" *ngIf="nzLoading"></span>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
  host: {
    class: 'ant-btn',
    '[class.ant-btn-primary]': `nzType === 'primary'`,
    '[class.ant-btn-dashed]': `nzType === 'dashed'`,
    // ...
  }
})
```

As you can see it is not a `@Directive` but a `@Component` that selects elements with the condition `button[nz-button]`.

Now this is the component I developed to wrap that component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'button, a',
  preserveWhitespaces: false,
  imports: [
    NzButtonModule
  ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  host: {
    'nz-button': '',
    class: 'btn',
    '[class.btn-primary]': `color === 'primary'`,
    '[class.btn-secondary]': `color === 'secondary'`,
    // ...
  }
})

export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() size: ButtonSize = 'md';
  @Input() shape: ButtonShape = 'default';
  @Input() color: ButtonColor = 'primary';
  @Input() fill: ButtonFill = 'solid';
  @Input() expand: ButtonExpand = 'default';
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that the button tag I place in the consumer components has all the `ng-zorro` attributes *and* mine too so I can implement new attributes to the native tag and override the `ant` styles in some cases.

In other words, I want to have `[nzType]` (from `ng-zorro`) and `shape` (from my `ButtonComponent`) both on a `<button>` tag.

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up extending `ng-zorro` component to inherit its Inputs on my custom component it was not exactly what I wanted because now I have to use `ng-zorro` inputs by their name but not my desired name. For example, I have to use it like `[nzSize]` but not `[size]`.

It is a workaround that will do the work but not a solid and complete solution.

I accept my solution until a better one comes.